# "error: Error parsing XML: junk after document element"

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

Eclipse is giving me this error in my `activity_main.xml` file, but I'm not sure why...

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:background="@drawable/titlebar"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="8dip" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:text="create account"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="32sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="sans" />

<com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/indicator"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

(The error annotation appears on the line where the `com.viewpagerindicator...` tab begins)
Any help or ideas would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you please post full error log?

Comment: How do I get the error log? Sorry, I'm new to Eclipse

Comment: From Window > Show View > Logcat

Answer (score 2):

You need to add:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

below the android namespace.

Comment: this is the perfect answer. why isnt it marked yet?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

at the very top of your xml file.
So the resulting xml should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/titlebar"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="8dip" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:text="create account"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```